# IBM Remote Supervisor Adapters(RSA ii) boot ISO

Tags: rsa, adapter, ibm

My company recently bought some add in IBM Remote Supervisor Adapters for our older x3550 servers. We got them installed and working, and left for the weekend. The idea was to get them to mount and boot a server ISO file and install windows over the weekend. However booting off the ISO file isn’t working.

I tried mounting the ISO(using clone drive)  on the workstation I am using to remote into the server with and then telling it to mount G drive, I have also told the RSA remote session to mount the ISO file directly but results in error 602 Invalid diskette boot record.

According to this link this should work just fine, it does mention I should create an unattended install ISO but I don’t need/want that.
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/toolsctr/v1r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fsgtk_sa_win%2Fremote_install.html

Does anyone have any experience doing this or any ideas?

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The servers needed to to have their BIOS and BMC updated using the IBM updatexpress installer.
Also the RSA adapters had to be updated with the specific firmware for them to work with the server, this firmware can be found under the RSA 2 section in the downloads for the x3550 M1. Even after that sometimes it takes at least one, sometimes two restarts for it to boot from the ISO file.